# How to disable delete by swipe on destructive UITableViewRowAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to disable swipe left triggering deleteAction? I need it to be invoked only by tapping delete button.

I have this code for providing actions.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { _, indexPath in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    })

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Tried this fix but it didn't work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        return .delete
    }

    return .none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I used `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` method instead of `editActionsForRowAt` and there is a property `performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe` on a `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` which can be disabled.